# Unbounded Fredholms operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Motivated by the situation of bounded [Fredholm operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator), I have the following question about "unbounded Fredholm operators".

Let $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ be two Hilbert spaces, and 
$$
D: \mathrm{dom}(D) \subset  \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_2
$$
be a densely defined a unbounded operator. If we assume that the image is closed, and that $\mathrm{ker}(D)$ and $\mathrm{cokernel}(D)$ are both finite dimensional, is true that 
$$
\mathrm{cokernel}(D) = \mathrm{ker}(D^*),
$$
where $D$ is the adjoint of $D$? Can you relax the assumptions on closure of the image, and/or dimensionality and still produce the smae result?

Comment: The equality holds for closed unbounded operators, provided one interprets "cokernel" as "quotient by the closure of the image".

Comment: @ André: What is a standard reference for this, or is it easy to see?

Comment: You can check it directly for closed self-adjoint operators by using the spectral theorem (i.e. check it for multiplication operators on $L^2(X)$ for some measure space $X$). Then use polar decomposition to reduce the case of an arbitrary closed operator to that of a self-adjoint operator. PS: this has nothing to do with the operator being Fredholm or not.

Comment: Please put this as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equality holds for closed unbounded operators, provided one interprets "cokernel" as "quotient by the closure of the image".

You can check it directly for closed self-adjoint operators by using the spectral theorem (i.e. check it for multiplication operators on $L^2(X)$ for some measure space $X$). Then use polar decomposition to reduce the case of an arbitrary closed operator to that of a self-adjoint operator.

PS: this has nothing to do with the operator being Fredholm or not.

Comment: Just to be sure, unlike for the Fredholm case, there exist closed unbounded operators whose image is not closed?

Comment: A closed self-adjoint operator rarely has closed image. The image is closed iff zero is an isolated point in the spectrum (a property which holds true for Fredholm operators).

Comment: Ok, I see - thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that this answer uses quite serious machinery. On the other hand the fact needed here is completely elementary and quite likely used in the development that leads to the spectral theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: $\mathrm{ker}(D^*)=\mathrm{Im}(D)^{\perp}$ for any $D$ densely defined.
If $x\in \mathrm{ker}(D^*)$ and $a\in \mathrm{Dom}(D)$, then $(x,Da)=(D^*x,a)=0$, so LHS in RHS. Conversely, if $y\in \mathrm{Im}(D)^{\perp}$, then $(y,D\cdot)=0$ on $\mathrm{Dom}(D)$, so $y\in \mathrm{Dom}(D^*)$ and $D^*y=0$, hence $y\in \mathrm{ker}(D^*)$, ie RHS in LHS. Now recall $\mathrm{Im}(D)^{\perp}=H_2/\overline{\mathrm{Im}(D)}$.